# Remove language dialects from Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, language-support, dictionary

When I compose a new email in Thunderbird and I want to change the spell checker language I can click on `Spelling` and switch between the installed languages. Unfortunately there are currently all kinds of different dialects installed for both English and German, making it rather cumbersome to select the one dialect I want to use. I just need English US and German DE.

**Question:** How can I uninstall all those additional dialects like `German (LU)`, or `English (CA)`?

[image]

Currently I have only installed the following three language packs in Ubuntu:

[image]

Additionally my package manager shows me I have installed the following locale package for Ubunut:

```
thunderbird-locale-de       
thunderbird-locale-en       
thunderbird-locale-en-gb    
thunderbird-locale-en-us    
thunderbird-locale-zh-cn    
thunderbird-locale-zh-hans
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with Thunderbird 38.8.0

Comment: Thunderbird uses hunspell, so this should answer it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5136/how-to-remove-all-that-country-specific-dictionaries-like-en-au-en-ca-de-ch

Comment: This is actually a tricky design issue. Related bug: https://launchpad.net/bugs/651586

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by uninstalling the respective `hunspell` packages:

First I searched for all installed `hunspell` packages:

```
aptitude search hunspell|grep ^i
```

Which returned this list:

```
i   hunspell-de-at   
i   hunspell-de-ch   
iB  hunspell-de-de   
i A hunspell-en-ca   
i A hunspell-en-gb   
i   hunspell-en-us   
i A hunspell-en-za   
i A libhunspell-1.3-0
```

Then I removed the unnecessary ones with:

```
sudo apt purge hunspell-de-at hunspell-de-ch hunspell-en-ca \
hunspell-en-gb hunspell-en-za
```

**Note:** A few redundancies still remain, which are caused by the fact that some packages install symlinks to other languages which then show up as duplicates in thunderbird. For example `hunspell-de-de` installs a symlink name `de_BE.aff` in `/usr/share/hunspell` which points to `de_DE.aff`. See https://launchpad.net/bugs/651586 (Thanks to Gunnar Hjalmarsson for pointing this out in the comments).

Comment: Hey, after all you are lucky to not have Spanish or Arabic dictionaries with a lot of symlinks. ;)

Comment: that's great, I wasn't aware of this. Well done.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 22.04. I have the same problem but nothing is found with the first code line. I also have the same superfluous dictionaries and the purge command doesn't find anything. Conclusion: it happens also without hunspell?

Answer (score 3):

You can find the installed dictionaries at `/usr/lib/thunderbird/dictionaries`
and delete the unwanted `.aff` and `.dic` dictionaries there.

Things change depending on Thunderbird and Ubuntu version so it's worth noting for future readers that I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and Thunderbird 38.8.0.

Comment: Notice that that dir is a link to hunspell --- so this is similar to http://askubuntu.com/a/545356/16395

Comment: This would require me to interfere with files that are managed by the  package manager. A better solution IMHO is to find the respective packages and then remove them with the package manager. See my own answer.